# Why was the motivation of this character at the end of Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

**Note: even though I’ve tried to guard against it this question and likely any answers will contain massive spoilers for Loki Season 1**

In *Loki* Episode 6 of Season 1

> He Who Remains states that he has been trying to get Loki and Sylvie to him so they can take over in a very elaborate plot.

What is not clear to me is why not simply bring them to him instead of this elaborate plot. I understood his main motivation was:

> He was tired of running the timeline and wanted to be “free” of that burden, but I don’t understand why all the misdirection was required. After all he’s presented as a very powerful being somehow.

Was this ever explained or, assuming the plot comes from the comics, is it explained there?

Comment: Something something the journey

Comment: Free will still exists, presumably he needs to know that these particular variants are worthy and have them in the right frame of mind. That’s part of the reason for Miss Minutes’ deal.

Comment: [Very related and possible duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251545/58193).

Comment: This is a duplicate, I agree my question is answered there.